# Booting "Linux from Scratch" doesn't bring up # prompt

Tags: kernel, grub, kernel-panic

I have been following [A Minimal Linux System from Scratch](https://sites.google.com/site/4utils/articles/minimal_linux_system/minimal-linux-system-from-scratch) in order to build a Linux with a small footprint (10MB or less).

I'm fairly certain that there were no errors up until the last point, where I'm actually testing the image, using the command `qemu-system-i386 -L . -hda minux.img`

Instead of actually booting to the `#` prompt as the tutorial showed, I'm greeted by the Grub Rescue Prompt. In order to attempt booting, I used `kernel /boot/kernel_name` then `boot`, which ultimately fails with:
[image: Grub 2 Output]

My `grub.conf` is below, identical to the one in the tutorial:

```
default 0
timeout 30
title Minux
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinux-2.6.21-1 root=/dev/hda1 rw
```

So far the only difference I've managed to find was in `fdisk`, where my starting sector is 2048, since it's the minimum I can set using fdisk and as a consequence the offset is bigger. Another difference is that I'm using x86_64-pc grub and some of my busybox libs are named differently, but this should not interfere with boot.

How could I fix the procedure to make my linux work? Or is there a better way to make a linux distribution under 10MB?

Comment: Perhaps the disk has a different name? The GRUB configuration shows `hda1`, maybe it is `sda1` or `vda1`? Or GRUB calls it something different, so that `root (hd0,0)` doesn't work?

Comment: isn't the `-hda` part supposed to attach it at hda? and since there's only one partition, shouldn't it be hda1?

Comment: Hmm, yes. I didn't see the qemu command.

Comment: `grub` and *minimal* are fairly at odds here, don't you think? Why are you using such a bloated bootloader at all?

Comment: @mikeserv `grub` was used in the tutorial I was folowing, so I guessed it was the way to go

Comment: How is it possible to get Linux installs using 10MB or less disk when the kernel is, like, 60MB on its own? I know that it's possible but would like to know how it's implemented.

Comment: Actually it's not that hard, I merely stripped everything I didn't need, like drivers and support for filesystems I didn't need. It's a simple interface where you uncheck those things. This was built mainly as a demo of how small Linux can actually be.

Answer (score 1):

let me try answer the second question about make a small system . since we are building on x86 i guess what is intended is to make a system to boot of a flash drive , rather than burn into embedded chips for which is a very different story .

consider drop disk images and use a cpio initramfs . then boot like this .

`qemu-system-i386 -kernel vmlinuz -initrd root.cpio.gz`

i love this because we have more flexibilites and don't have to be confused with disk locations .

i also suggest *grub4dos* the bootloader . despite "dos" in the name , it can be installed from linux and boot linux kernels . the installation is as simple as write an mbr and copy one 213k file to *any partition* . and grub4dos recognises many filesystems .

---

besides , in your configuration it seems you didn't set up grub right , for there is a *rescue* console showed . even though you should type `kernel /boot/kernel_name` with a "root=" before `boot` .

and on my machine the qemu guest kernel recognises the disk image as "/dev/sda" instead of "/dev/hda" .